# Powershell - extracting specific string

Tags: powershell, api

I need to get a token which I'm getting from one API call to use it in another API call.

I'm trying to extract the access_token part somehow, to define it as a variable which I use in the 2'nd call.

My command:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI_TOKEN -Method Post -Headers $HEADERS_TOKEN -Body $BODY_TOKEN | Select-String -pattern access_token`

Output:

```
@{access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI4dDdPZUhRa1prall4SW1NWko3YVROanFMeW11WngwNWhvWTBxekxBbk1jIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2MTI4Mjg0OTMsImlhdCI6MTYxMjgyODQzMywianRpIjoiZGZkNTY5ZGUtYWUyZ
i00NDRhLTk0NTgtNzY2NWYwN2UzZjkyIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly92ZXJpZmljYXRpb24taWFtLXdydS50ZWxpdGNhYXNtZ210LnQtaW50ZXJuYWwuY29tL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjMwZjIyZDFhLTYxZTQtNGM5YS05OGU1LTU0MjhmZWM1M
zViMiIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI4NjRlODYxNi00NTJlLTRiNGItYjBkMC1kMjIxYjEwNDA5OWUiLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwic2NvcGUiOiJwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlL
CJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.Kz4zsCKyFFrvxm4ZLaf-pE2iDQOFF_Y_HPSTWslVBKqu9QnMaPVQINWENvcydP5SKg4ABza3OGkLreBhPmfeDGupRVIQNU5h4C5AewbVcNke1Drvi2CE3nEopqigIYE1Ab_GwovXT8MuXt1NTbpPtLgnjVuj-Q4P
pHKvdtHomf_DY1PTR9aFQ6CLohHmLEjBiOtOcnce0r6ZI_--XFDL81UkOOEW062LMYqyUV-jb8uRjlbUuKWHdUKnlr2H_bQNFQ5vVvi0BgevDrBc6E4oECiMnpIVFitXVIF6ZtPhKT-lyGkyZ7oaXERT-v_AcQLy2-t-cscsd0bGCL2zbUOELw; expires_in=60; r
efresh_expires_in=1800; refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJlNTkxZWEyZC1jMDM1LTQ4YWUtYWY0Yi0wYjc1ZGY4YzA5ZmIifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2MTI4MzAyMzMsImlhdCI6MTYxMjgyODQzMywianRpIjoiMTA
wNjZhYWYtMGIzNC00MTBjLWI2MTItNmFmNDI5NjAwNDQ2IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly92ZXJpZmljYXRpb24taWFtLXdydS50ZWxpdGNhYXNtZ210LnQtaW50ZXJuYWwuY29tL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vdmVyaWZpY2F0aW9uLWl
hbS13cnUudGVsaXRjYWFzbWdtdC50LWludGVybmFsLmNvbS9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9tYXN0ZXIiLCJzdWIiOiIzMGYyMmQxYS02MWU0LTRjOWEtOThlNS01NDI4ZmVjNTM1YjIiLCJ0eXAiOiJSZWZyZXNoIiwiYXpwIjoiYWRtaW4tY2xpIiwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI
6Ijg2NGU4NjE2LTQ1MmUtNGI0Yi1iMGQwLWQyMjFiMTA0MDk5ZSIsInNjb3BlIjoicHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.fwY1IUnWkS-pMzy_-pBiqch4dL4eLMvCPSKaAsGeqqw; token_type=bearer; not-before-policy=0; session_state=864e8616-452e-4
b4b-b0d0-d221b104099e; scope=profile email}
```

This output contains items I don't need. Is it possible to extract the string which starts with access_token=blahblah and until the `;` sign only (up until expires_in=60 basically)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Capture your result in a variable, then replace everything except the token with something like `$Results -replace '^.*access_token=(.*?);.*','$1'`

Comment: You'll probably find it easier to extract the access token if you _don't_ pipe the output from `Invoke-RestMethod` to `Select-String`.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thank you for your answer, but because of many broken lines (spaces) in that output that didn't really workout in a way that it would be consumable by the next step of the script, where I need to provide the bearer token for authentication.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, maybe that is the case indeed, but then output is very long and not suitable for substitution, I can't paste it, too many characters. I'm not sure what would be the best practice in this case, I will google how people build such API calls scripts, hopefully i will find something. I need to get token in the first step, then in the 2'nd step add users to the system using that bearing token for authorization.

Comment: What does `(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI_TOKEN -Method Post -Headers $HEADERS_TOKEN -Body $BODY_TOKEN).GetType()` reveal? Is is a `string`, or a `PSObject` ?

Comment: BaseType: System.Object |  Name:PSCustomObject

Comment: @Theo I've tried now this: ```Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI_TOKEN -Method Post -Headers $HEADERS_TOKEN -Body $BODY_TOKEN | Select-Object  access_token | Tee-Object -Variable Token``` . But when I do  ```echo $Token ``` only 1/3 of the whole token approximately, apparently somehow the line are cut off because of the spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have shown that the output of the `Invoke-RestMethod` is a PSCustomObject, you can simply reference the access_token property by doing this:

```
$token = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI_TOKEN -Method Post -Headers $HEADERS_TOKEN -Body $BODY_TOKEN).access_token
```